# Docker build can't find Dockerfile

Tags: docker, blazor, github-actions

I have a GitHub repo with a MubBlazor project. It is just a kind of playground for me and my friend. We plan on following clean architecture, based on the following [YouTube tutorial by Frank Liu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EluvVXA_Rto&ab_channel=FrankLiu).
We only have the web app part by now as you can see in the current repo structure.

I want to use a self-hosted GitHub Actions runner to check out my code, build a Docker image and run that image on the same Raspberry Pi, so me and my friend can actually see the project on a server, not just by using the local Visual Studio IIS-Express hosting.

However each GitHub Actions run fails when trying to build the Docker image:

```
Run sudo docker build -t playground-f Dockerfile ./
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile:
#1 transferring dockerfile: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1403914947/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I feel like a copy of my repo doesn't reach the runner, if that makes sense. Because the build fails, I don't know if the rest of the process would work.

Current file/repo structure:

```
Playground
├── .github/workflows
│   ├── main.yml
├── Playground.WebApp
│   ├── Pages
│   ├── Properties
│   ├── Shared
│   ├── wwwroot
│   ├── App.razor
│   ├── Program.cs
│   ├── Playground.WebApp.csproj
│   ├── Playground.WebApp.sln
│   ├── _Imports.razor
├── Dockerfile
├── Spielplatz.sln
├── nginx.conf
```

Current workflow file:

```yaml
name: Build and launch playground
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  create_image_and_run_it:    
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: sudo docker build -t playground -f Dockerfile ./
      - run: sudo docker run -p 8080:80 playground
```

Current Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY Playground.sln ./
COPY ./Playground.WebApp/Playground.WebApp.csproj ./Playground.WebApp

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM nginx:1.23.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/out/wwwroot /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: It seems your code isn't available to the runner, and as a result, the Docker build step can't find the Dockerfile.
I think your GitHub Actions workflow does not have a step to check out the repository before trying to build the Docker image.
Can you edit this on your workflow and try:

runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

Comment: Seems like you forgot to checkout the project. Please checkout the project first using the [`checkout` action (`github.com`)](https://github.com/actions/checkout).

Comment: Validate if Dockerfile exist is being pushed (gitignore) and/or remove this section from your yaml `-f Dockerfile ./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With github-actions, the project is not checked out automatically; we need to checkout the project explicitly. For this, the github-team provides the [`checkout` action (`github.com`)](https://github.com/actions/checkout). Using it is as simple as adding

```yaml
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
```

to the `steps`-list of a given workflow.